# I am having trouble because of the active directory profiles

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to run this macro in an active directory profile but I get a 9105 runtime error but this doesn't happen when I try to run this macro in any other profile.

```
Sub Macrofinal()
Dim filePath As String
If Environ("Username") = "benjy" Then
filePath = "c:\user\benjy.AD\Desktop\CancellationAudit.xlsx"
Else
filePath = "c:\user\%USERNAME%\Desktop\CancellationAudit.xlsx"
End If
Debug.Print filePath
ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
    filePath, ConfirmConversions:= _
    False, ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
    WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:= _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=" & filePath & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";Jet OLEDB:System database="""";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=37;Jet OLEDB:Databas" _
    , SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `'Book Of Business-Cancellation A$'`", _
    SQLStatement1:="", SubType:=wdMergeSubTypeAccess
    

    With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
       .MailAddressFieldName = "F7"
        .Destination = wdSendToEmail
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = 5
            .LastRecord = -1
            
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
Application.Quit _
 SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges, OriginalFormat:=wdWordDocument
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `OpenDataSource` doesn't translate the  `%USERNAME%` to the actual path - try doing that before running the mail merge

Comment: Are you actually using "C:\user\" or "C:\Users\" ?

Comment: Try `filePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\CancellationAudit.xlsx"`